# Why is value undefined in unit tests, but has truthy value when checked in browser?

Tags: angular, jasmine, dom-events

I'm writing some unit tests for an Angular component and I can't seem to figure out why the ***panelRef*** variable in the code bellow is ***undefined*** when the unit test is executed, but is a ***div*** element when logged and checked in devtools while running the app. I would have expected to be a ***div*** also in the unit test.

**Component snippet:**

```
  this.inputFocusListenerFn = this.renderer.listen(locationInputRef, 'focus', () => {
    const panelRef = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.p-autocomplete-panel')[0];

    if (panelRef) {
      console.log('panelRef=', panelRef);
      this.renderer.setStyle(panelRef, 'visibility', 'visible');
    }
  });
```

**Browser log:**

[image]

**Unit test snippet:**

```
it('should make the autocomplete suggestions panel visible when ' +
      'autocomplete input is focused', () => {
      const { fixture } = getFixture();
      const autocompleteInput = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('p-autoComplete')[0];

      autocompleteInput.focus();

      const autocompletePanel = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('div.p-autocomplete-panel')[0];
      console.log(autocompletePanel); // ---> undefined
    });
```

**Unit test log:**

[image]

I would expect the difference of value to be due to the asynchronous aspect of the Renderer listener that might require some handling in the test to make the ***panelRef*** also assigned in the test, but at this point it's just a hunch.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using this library: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete

In order for Angular to know how to paint that element for unit tests just like how it is when you serve the app, you have to configure the `TestBed.configureTestingModule({})` similarly.

I am thinking you need:

```
import {AutoCompleteModule} from 'primeng/autocomplete';
....
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [AutoCompleteModule],
  // the rest of stuff.
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Yes, I am using primeng components and it totally makes sense that you thought about a possible missing import, but it was already there in my case. Anyways, thanks for the effort!

Comment: I would expect to be something about the way I get the autocompletePanel reference OR the view not being updated / settled until the element query is executed.

Comment: addition to the previous comment:  or the event triggering the log in the browser not to be a focus event, but maybe a click. So, different events in the Renderer2 listener / unit test act phase

Comment: Yes all of those are possible. Maybe try a `fixture.detectChanges()` and see what `panelRef` is in `inputFocusListenerFn` and if it makes it inside of the `if`.

Comment: it didn't make it it inside the IF statement. fixture.detectChanges did not help either

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the expected value for **autocompletePanel** in the unit test by making this update in the component code:

```
this.inputFocusListenerFn = this.renderer.listen(locationInputRef, 'focus', () => {
  const panelRef = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.p-autocomplete-panel')[0];

  this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <--- the update

  if (panelRef) {
    console.log('panelRef=', panelRef);
    this.renderer.setStyle(panelRef, 'visibility', 'visible');
  }
});
```

I'm not happy with this line of code being added in the component since it is not needed for the component's functionality (it's "needed" just by the unit test), so I consider it a workaround that has to go as soon as possible.